# Can a ring without unity have a non-trivial subring with unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The original problem was to prove that for any commutative ring R, there is a canonical (unique) ring homomorphism from Z to R. The problem would be simple, if R has $1_R$ and we can let the homomorphism map $\phi$ sends $0$ to $0_R$ and $1$ to $1_R$. But if R doesn't have an identity, and $\phi(Z)$ forms a subring of $R$ with unity $\phi(1)$, then the Rng $R$ has a subring with unity. If ring without unity can only have a trivial subring with unity, $\phi$ must be the trivial map, and the proof would be complete. But I'm not sure of this part. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are at least three ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. Only one respects the identity.

Comment: IMHO, i think a complete answer is a combination of subrosar's and Robert Lewis'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many "commutative rings" are assumed from context to contain the identity, and homomorphisms of these rings must take the identity to the identity. If that is the case, define $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to R$ so that $\phi(n)=1_R+...+1_R$ (n times).

If this is not assumed, it is false that for any commutative ring $R$ there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to R.$ For example if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ either the trivial map or the identity map is a homomorphism in the non-unital ring sense.

Comment: IMHO, i think a complete answer is a combination of subrosar's and Robert Lewis'. but anyhoo i upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the ring $\Bbb Z \oplus 2\Bbb Z$, with componentwise addition and multiplication; it has no unit, but the subring $\Bbb Z$ (first component) is a unital ring.

Comment: IMHO, i think a complete answer is a combination of subrosar's and Robert Lewis'. but anyhoo i upvoted.